# multiple timers when timer ends

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to create a series of timers after one timer ends.

I have written the below but looking at it I don't believe this is the best method of doing what I want.

I am unsure how to loop through this code while changing the variables I have set depending on where the timer is at.

```
object : CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
    override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
        timerField.setText("$timer1" + millisUntilFinished / 1000)
    }

    override fun onFinish() {

        object : CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                timerField.setText("$timer2" + millisUntilFinished / 1000)
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                timerField.setText("$release" )
                object : CountDownTimer(8000, 1000) {
                    override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                        timerField.setText("$timer3" + millisUntilFinished / 1000)
                    }

                    override fun onFinish() {
                        timerField.setText("$timer4" )

                    }

                }.start()
            }

        }.start()
    }
}.start()
```

Comment: Does the code above not do what you want? If not, then you'll need to describe exactly what the expected behavior is. Or are you just asking if there's a cleaner way to write the same behavior as above?

Comment: Yeah the code above works. 
I just feel this isn’t a clean way of solving it.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a suspend function with similar behavior to CountDownTimer:

```
suspend fun countDown(millisInFuture: Long, interval: Long, onTick: (millisUntilFinished: Long) -> Unit) {
    var remaining = millisInFuture
    while (remaining > interval) {
        delay(interval)
        remaining -= interval
        onTick(remaining)
    }
    delay(remaining)
}
```

and use it like this:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    countDown(5000L, 1000L) { millisUntilFinished ->
        timerField.setText("$timer1" + millisUntilFinished / 1000)
    }
    countDown(5000L, 1000L) { millisUntilFinished ->
        timerField.setText("$timer2" + millisUntilFinished / 1000)
    }
    timerField.setText("$release" )
    countDown(8000L, 1000L) { millisUntilFinished ->
        timerField.setText("$timer3" + millisUntilFinished / 1000)
    }
    timerField.setText("$timer4")
}
```

By using a `lifecycleScope` coroutine, this also has the advantage over your code of not leaking your views if the Activity/Fragment is closed while the timer is running.

Comment: Thanks Tenfour this seems to work a lot better much appreciated.